# Dynamic mapping re-rendering issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I had this mapping problem yesterday. So the whole div is mapped and constructed dynamically by mapping the videos array. I also had a HTML video tag inside and wanted to showcase each video inside by clicking on the preview button. The plan was to access that particular video by using the index from the mapping `(m, i)`.

Here comes the problem. No matter which video I clicked, the video that was being presented was always the last video. It seems that when I clicked to open a HTML5 with the video inside, the whole page gets re-rendered - thus the mapping is redone again - and showing my only the last video in the array.

I did manage to find a way around this (by giving value (0-5) to the HTML rows on each video and getting that value by the click and accessing the video in the array using that number), but that is not the correct way and I am still curious why I was not able to see the correct video done with the mapping.

Can someone care to explain this to me? Here is the code:

```
import { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import { FaCamera } from 'react-icons/fa'
import { FaInfo } from 'react-icons/fa'
import { GiRapidshareArrow } from 'react-icons/gi'
import { AiOutlineCloseCircle } from 'react-icons/ai'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

import { CarContext } from '../_app'

export default function SubmitSegment() {

    const router = useRouter()

    const { shootingSegment, freeShotForm, redoSegmentNumber, setRedoSegmentNumber } = useContext(CarContext)

    const [displayRecordedVideo, setDisplayRecordedVideo] = useState({
        display: false,
    })

    const flipVideo = () => {
        setDisplayRecordedVideo({
            display:!displayRecordedVideo.display
        })
    }

    const consoleLogTheState = () => {
        console.log(shootingSegment.videoBlobs, freeShotForm)
    }

    const getHTMLRowName = (e) => {
        const currentRow = e.currentTarget.id
        setRedoSegmentNumber({
            numero:currentRow
        })
    }

    const makeNumber = parseInt(redoSegmentNumber.numero)

    return (
        <div className='background-semi-black-layer'>
            <div className='CarLife-repeating-title'>
                <div className='carlife-header-text'>
                    CarLife
                    <div className='carlife-header-symbol'>
                        &trade;
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            
            <div className='submit-page-body-free-shot'>

                {  shootingSegment.videoBlobs.map( (m,i) =>     
                    <div className='elements-row-div-free-shot' key={i} id={i} onClick={getHTMLRowName} >
                    <div className='left-side-row' > 
                        <button className='entry-btn' onClick={flipVideo} key={i} >
                            <FaCamera className='submit-camera-icon-left'  />
                          {  displayRecordedVideo.display &&
                          
                                    <div className='display-current-step-recorded-video' key={i} >
                                        <AiOutlineCloseCircle onClick={flipVideo} className='exit-preview-your-recorded-video-icon'  />
                                        <video className='video-source' controls key={i}>
                                            console.log(i)
                                            <source src={shootingSegment.videoBlobs[makeNumber]}  />
                                        </video>
                                    </div>
                                }
                        </button>
                        <p className='text-under-camera-left' >Segment #{i+1}</p>
                    </div>

                    <div className='right-side-row-free-shot' >     
                            <Link href='/free-shot/override-segment'>
                                <a>
                                <GiRapidshareArrow className='submit-icon-right-free-shot'  />
                                </a>
                                </Link>
                        <p className='text-under-camera-left'  >Redo this segment</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    
                    ) }
               
            </div>

            <div className='submit-button-free-shot'>
            <button className='next-step-button' onClick={consoleLogTheState} >Submit
                    <p> > </p>
                    </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The issue is the source `src`. Ok, I am editing and inserting the whole code. The shooting segment is a global state transferred with Context:

```js
const [shootingSegment, setShootingSegment] = useState({
      segmentComplete: false,
      videoBlobs: [video1, video2, video3, video4, video5...]
})
```

The array elements are populated here as the user goes from step 1 to 8 and shoots videos of himself. For the popHTMLBox, I just changed the name of the function for StackOverflow here so it makes more sense of what it does, here it's named FlipVideo.

Comment: Can you provide more of this component? It is hard to tell what the issue is from the snippet provided. I will say that you generally should not use the index as the key. That may not be the issue here, but it will lead to buggy behavior, particularly when your array changes. Also, you are putting a lot of unnecessary `key`properties. Only the `elements-row-div` needs the `key`.

Comment: Yes, i only put the keys after not being able to fix it and thought it may help, originally i only had it 2 keys. That is the whole component. It auto mapping a video array and only showing the last video in the array, instead of the particular one selected by the button generated to open it.

Comment: That might be the render function, but it certainly isn't the whole component definition. For instance, we don't see you assign shootingSegment, displayRecordedVideo, popHTML5Box, or globalState

Comment: @rfestag Yes, now i pasted the whole component, with the real names  (flipVideo instead of popHTMLBox) and the global state that is transfered here. Maybe this can give you a better perspective.

Comment: When you say you worked around the issue by giving each html row a "value" from 0-5, does that mean you gave them a string id instead of trying to use the index as the `key`? One thing that seems weird here is that, if ` displayRecordedVideo.display` is true, you'll get multiple `video` tags (one for each element), all with the same source. Is that intended/expected? Also, have you verified that `redoSegmentNumber.numero` is the expected value on a click?